# Redeploy and Undeploy API's in WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We referred the below documentation from WSO2 APIM which has out of the box API's to check the health check, undeploy or redeploy the imported API's in WSO2 APIM.

I tested these API's with few of our existing imported API's and got success response but still I don't see API's getting undeployed WSO2 API Publisher.

Can someone please help me understand how these API's are working out.

Comment: Can you add the missing documentation link? Are you unable to undeploy the API?

Comment: Apologies, adding the missing url  https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/reference/product-apis/gateway-apis/gateway-v2/gateway-v2/

Answer (score 0):

The Gateway REST API you have mentioned is used to directly undeploy or redeploy APIs from the synapse gateway. This does not consider the revisions and their status available in the Publisher. If you try to invoke the API after undeploying it using this API, you will not be able to do so since it no longer exists in the gateway.

To properly deploy or undeploy APIs in the gateway using the Control Plane (Publisher), you can use the Publisher REST APIs [1]. This will deploy/undeploy the revision from the control plane side first and then carry out the flow involved with the Gateway REST API to deploy or undeploy the API in the Gateway.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v4/publisher-v4/#tag/API-Revisions/operation/deployAPIRevision